# (Javascript) Bouncing balls clip into wall

Tags: javascript, physics

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
 var context,
  width = window.screen.availWidth - 120,
  height = window.screen.availHeight - 120,
  xTemp, 
  yTemp,
  x = [], 
  y = [], 
  dx = [0], 
  dy = [5], 
  gravity = [1],
  bounceTime = [1],
  canvas = document.getElementById("bouncingField"), 
  isSpawned = 0,
  image = new Image();
  
 document.getElementById("bouncingField").width = width;
 document.getElementById("bouncingField").height = height;
 
 //Image to use as ball texture
 image.src = "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/soccer-ball-icon-14.png";
  
 //Run func init on page load
 window.onload = init;
 
 //Get 2d context and repaint every 10 milliseconds
 context = bouncingField.getContext('2d');
 setInterval(repaint, 10);
 
 canvas.onclick = function setSpawnTrue(){
  if(!isSpawned){
   x[0] = xTemp;
   y[0] = yTemp;
  } else{
   x.push(xTemp);
   y.push(yTemp);
   dx.push(0);
   dy.push(5);
   gravity.push(1);
   bounceTime.push(1);
  }
  
  isSpawned = 1;
 }
 
 //Draws the various entities
 function draw(){
  context = bouncingField.getContext('2d');
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){ 
   //context.beginPath();
   //context.fillStyle = "#00ccff";
   //Draw circles of r = 25 at coordinates x and y
   //context.arc(x[i], y[i], 25, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
   context.drawImage(image, x[i], y[i], 50, 50);
   //context.closePath();
   //context.fill();
  }
 }

 //Repaints entities, essentially animating them 
 function repaint(){
  for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
   context.clearRect(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
   if(x[i] < 20 || x[i] > width) dx[i] *= -1;
   if(y[i] < 20 || y[i] > height) {
    dy[i] *= -1;
    //We add bounceTime to dy so that it gradually loses speed
    dy[i] += bounceTime[i];
    //Inverting graviy to slow down on rise
    gravity[i] *= -1;
   }
   
   x[i] += dx[i];
   //Gravity affects the ball bounce speed, that gradually slows down.
   y[i] += dy[i] + gravity[i];
   //bounceTime gradually reduces the amount of speed the ball has
   gravity[i] += 0.2 * bounceTime[i];
   bounceTime[i] += 0.01;
   if(isSpawned){
    draw();
   }
  }
 }
 
 //Initializes Event.MOUSEMOVE to capture cursor coordinates
 function init(){
  if(window.Event){
   document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
  }
  document.onmousemove = getCoordinates;
 }
  
 //Gets mouse coordinates and puts them into xTemp and yTemp
 function getCoordinates(e){
  xTemp = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
  yTemp = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollRight ? document.documentElement.scrollRight : document.body.scrollRight);
  xTemp -= 14;
  yTemp -= 14;
 }
});
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #555555;
}

#bouncingField{
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 10px;
 border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>
   Wingin' it
  </TITLE>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 
 </HEAD>
 
 <BODY>
  <CANVAS id="bouncingField" width="0" height="0"></CANVAS>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm working on a simple JavaScript project to create bouncing balls that simulate gravity and that bounce off of the floor or the walls. The problem is that sometimes they clip into the floor and "spaz out" until they disappear from the screen. Any clue why? I've been trying to figure it out by adding a tiny time-out every time it collides but JS doesn't have sleep so I'm just confused now.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This site isn't designed to search through and debug your code for you — feel free to come back and post a question if you have a *real* question

Comment: This is my code, it doesn't work. Make it work !

Comment: @Alex Leonardi You have a changing velocity on your bouncing ball, so depending on how close the ball is to the colliding object on the cycle before the collision it may not manage to get out on the next cycle. This would cause it to become "stuck" to the colliding object.

Comment: @Alex Leonardi In order to fix it you could modify your bounce to occur just before collision instead of just after

Comment: @NickZuber I'm sorry? I can't request minor help with physics in my own program because I need to be scared of two wannabe bullies? Maybe you two are the ones who shouldn't be here and intoxicating the community.

Comment: @42shadow42 Thank you 42shadow42, but are you sure it is possible to have it bounce before collision? if ( y[i] > height) is my collision detection. If I don't detect it, how do I bounce it? o.o

Comment: @AlexLeonardi I'm sorry if my tone came off as hostile — that was not my intention. What I meant to say way questions requesting to debug code are inappropriate for this site

Comment: My guess is the issue is likely a result of the ball moving too fast, or not fast enough during a collision resulting in the ball falling outside the play field.  I'll check more formally now.

Comment: @JonSG Thank you. The collision happens before the ball is re-painted onto the canvas. Essentially you could say that the ball movement and collision detection are not two separate things. It's strange that this is happening :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps.  the tricky part is making a convincing "stop".

```js
function getCoordinates(event) { return { x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY }; }

function spawnBall(coords, x, y, dx, dy){
    x.push(coords.x);
    y.push(coords.y);
    dx.push(0);
    dy.push(2);
}

// =========================
// Draws the various entities
// =========================
function draw(canvas, image, x, y, width, height) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){ context.drawImage(image, x[i], y[i], width, height); }
}
// =========================

// =========================
// At the moment all this is concerned with is the "floor"
// =========================
function move(x, y, dx, dy, gravity, bounciness, floor){
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
      // =========================
      // Ball is close to the floor and not moving very fast, set it to rest
      // otherwise it bounces forever.
      // =========================
      if (y[i] >= floor - 10 && Math.abs(dy[i]) <= 2 * gravity) {
          dy[i] = 0;
          y[i] = floor;
          continue;
      }
      // =========================

      // =========================
      // Update the speed and position
      // =========================
      dy[i] += gravity;
      y[i] += dy[i];
      // =========================

      // =========================
      // Simulate a bounce if we "hit" the floor
      // =========================
      if(y[i] > floor) {
          y[i] = floor - (y[i] - floor);
          dy[i] = -1.0 * bounciness * dy[i];
      }
      // =========================
  }
}
// =========================

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("bouncingField");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 50;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 50;

    //Image to use as ball texture
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/soccer-ball-icon-14.png";

    var gravity = 1;
    var ballSize = 50;
    var ballBounciness = 0.8;
    var floor = canvas.height - ballSize;

    var x = [];
    var y = [];
    var dx = [];
    var dy = [];

    // =========================
    // This can be done via requestAnimationFrame()
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame
    // =========================
    var isSpawned = false;
    setInterval(function(){
        if(!isSpawned){ return; }
        move(x, y, dx, dy, gravity, ballBounciness, floor)
        draw(canvas, image, x, y, ballSize, ballSize);
    }, 10);
    // =========================

    // =========================
    // Add a ball
    // =========================
    canvas.onclick = function(event) {
        isSpawned = true;
        var coords = getCoordinates(event);
        spawnBall(coords, x, y, dx, dy);
    }
    // =========================
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555555;
}
#bouncingField {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="bouncingField"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you. This gave me an idea to reset the y of the ball every time it bounces to the floor Y - 40, to compensate for loss of cycles. :)